# mysql user authentication for nodeftpd

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I would like to use nodeftpd with mysql authentication, but the problem is connection.query() is async and script finishes before mysql returns results.

Although, I have worked out a solution already but it's a hack and not really a solution and is ugly. So how to use mysql to authenticate in the command:pass of the [nodeftpd](https://github.com/alanszlosek/nodeftpd) library

So its more of a how to asynch properly, probably!

```
conn.on('command:pass', function(pass, success, failure) {

    if(pass)
     con.query('select * from wp_users where user_login = ? and user_pass = ?',[username, pass], function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length > 0  ){
            success();
            return;
        }else{
            failure();
            return;
        }
        console.log('yy');

    });
     console.log('xx');
     failure();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
conn.on('command:pass', function(pass, success, failure) {
var self = this;

    if(pass)
      this.validateUser(username,pass,function(res){
       if(res) { 
              success();
       } else {
              failure();
       }
   });
    return;
});

validateUser = function(username,pass,callback) {
con.query('select * from wp_users where user_login = ? and user_pass = ?',[username, pass], function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length > 0  ){
            callback(true);
        }else{
    callback(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it is working! can you explain why its working with an extra function instead of calling con.query directly inside command:pass callback?

Comment: In your case you needed the blocking code, where until and unless user is validated program should no go further. The code which you were using was totally async and thats why next line of code getting executed without even waiting for login operation.